# c++ reading integers from binary file, missing some data

Tags: c++, file, io, binary

I am saving 100,000 integers to a binary file using:

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        temp = generateRand(99999);
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&temp),sizeof(temp));
    }
```

and from this file, I'm trying to read integers, and save them into a vector.

```
ifstream ifile;
ifile.open("test.bin",ios::binary);

ifile.seekg(0, ifile.end);
long size = ifile.tellg();
ifile.seekg(0, ifile.beg);

int restore = 0;
int count = 0;

while(ifile.tellg() < size){
    ifile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&restore), sizeof(restore));
    v.push_back(restore);
    count++;
}
```

However it seems like I can only read 99328 integers, not 100000. I am relatively new with read/write with binary files, so can you guys help me?

Comment: what is the type of `temp`? what is the size of the file you get? how do you define/open `file` and `ifile`?

Comment: oh, temp is of type int. generateRand function just generates random integers.

Comment: do you close or destroy `file` before reading?

Comment: no. I close file and ifile at the very end.

Comment: well there's your answer)

Comment: the size variable has a value of :397312

Comment: oh...hahah thank you Ap31!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `file` object is still open when the reading commences, which results in the described behavior.

Try calling `file.close()` to flush the buffer and only after that initialize `ifile`.

Also you will find that reading the whole vector at once can considerably speed up the process.

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me. May be you forgot to use the `ios::binary` flag or to close the streams?

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void write() {
  ofstream file;
  file.open("temp.data", ios::binary);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    int temp = 0; // I don't know the generateRandom(...) function
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&temp),sizeof(temp));
  }
}

void read() {
  ifstream ifile;
  ifile.open("temp.data", ios::binary);

  ifile.seekg(0, ifile.end);
  long size = ifile.tellg();
  ifile.seekg(0, ifile.beg);

  int restore = 0;
  vector<int> v;
  while(ifile.tellg() < size){
    ifile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&restore), sizeof(restore));
    v.push_back(restore);
  }

  cout << v.size() << endl;
}

int main()
{
  write();
  read();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I has to file.close() to flush the buffer!

Comment: +1 - A better program structure solves the problem by automatically closing the output file when it goes out of scope.

Comment: oh so if you use functions like above--write() and read() functions, you dont explicitly have to use close() function?

Comment: Yes, when the `ofstream` or `ifstream` object is destroyed it is automatically closed too.

Comment: Thank you so much cbuchart.